# jQuery .data() replace nested objects' properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery's [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store some data using nested objects like this:

```
$('div.divwithdata').data('somedata', {
    'a': {
        'b': {
            'c' : {}
        }
    }
});
```

However my question is: **Is there a way to replace nested object's property without overwriting the whole object ?**

I tought it could be done with `.data('somedata.a.b', 'newdata')` or `.data('somedata[a][b]', 'newdata')`, but none of them worked.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/byhas/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `data()` stores references, you can use its [getter form](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) and directly update the object it returns:

```
$("div.divwithdata").data("somedata").a.b = "newdata";
```

Or, using bracket notation:

```
$("div.divwithdata").data("somedata")["a"]["b"] = "newdata";
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('div.divwithdata').data('somedata').a = something`... or `$('div.divwithdata').data('somedata').a.b.c = "test";`

This works;